# How does this formula return the last non-zero value in a range

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook with 1, 4, 0, 100, 0, 0 distributed across the range A1 to A6.

A formula `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A6<>0),A1:A6)` returns me the last non-zero element in that range: `100` in this case. It's clever enough to step over the 0 between 4 and 100.

It's not my workbook and can't reach the author.

But how does the formula work?

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1043140-explain-lookup-2-1-a2-a10-d2-b2-b10.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `2` can be any number greater than 1 and work.

The `(A1:A6<>0)` is returning TRUE/FALSE which when being used as a denominator turns to 1/0 respectively.

So the `1/(A1:A6<>0)` returns an array of 1s and #DIV0 error.  For your instance: `{1,1,#DIV0,1,#DIV0,#DIV0}`

The Lookup looks for best fit, as in where the `2` is greater than the value in the array but less than the next or the last number in the array.  So it finds the last `1` in the returned array.

It then uses that relative position `4` to return the forth value in the third criterion range: the value in `A4` in this case.